# Sending Files Via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

Is there any way of sending files through bluetooth, from one computer to another?

Comment: Without more information about your environment (which OS(s)?, do you know which bluetooth stack is in use if not the default that comes with the OS?) the only answer that can be given is a similarly un-detailed "yes, the bluetooth specs define protocols for sending files from one device to another, if both devices support a relevant profile such as FTP or GEOP".

Answer (score 1):

Its not very hard to send files via Bluetooth, though I would recommend against it if the file is particularly large, as Bluetooth connections aren't particularly fast.

In Windows XP, just right click a file -> Send -> via Bluetooth. Of course, other bluetooth device needs to be paired. Here's a decent write up on [sending files via Bluetooth](http://www.oreillynet.com/wireless/2003/09/18/winxpunwired.html).